# how to extract the real used permissions in Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest

In Android Apps, if one App wants some permissions, it will apply for them in the AndroidManifest.xml file. But most apps will apply for more than they need.
Is there any tools that can distill the permissions from source code exclude AndroidManifest.xml? Or is it worthwhile doing the work?

Comment: Technically this is not possible, as the behaviour of an app with inputs is hard to bound.  Static analysis tools may attempt to capture the more obvious usages though.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37546500/1770868

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36937109/1770868