# Android 6.0 multiple permissions

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I know that Android 6.0 has new permissions and I know I can call them with something like this

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        new String[] { 
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, PERMISSION_WRITE_STORAGE);
}
```

Today I saw a Google app which needs 3 permissions: contacts, sms and camera. It's making a page 1-3 and calls them all together at the same time to activate.

Can anybody tell me how I can call 4 permissions to activate at the same time like sms, camera, contacts and storage?

Example (forgot the name of the google app :( )
The app needs sms,contacts and camera

the app asked me (and made a dialog page1-3) activate sms, activate contacts and then camera. 
So this google app was calling all 3 required permissions together and my question is how can i achive the same ?

Comment: can you be more specific or share what you have seen and want to implement?

Comment: Calling all 4 permissions at the same time in android 6.0 because "this" app needs 4 permissions. and this google app made it very smart calling them all together and as i mentiond makes page 1-3 to activate all 3 on the fly  ..so how can i make the same ? calling 4 permissions together at the same time to activate them

Comment: Just add all the permissions you wish inside the String[] array.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

Just include all 4 permissions in the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(...)` call and Android will automatically page them together like you mentioned.

I have a helper method to check multiple permissions and see if any of them are not granted.

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or in Kotlin:

```
fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean = permissions.all {
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}
```

Then just send it all of the permissions.  Android will ask only for the ones it needs.

```
// The request code used in ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()
// and returned in the Activity's onRequestPermissionsResult()
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
  android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
  android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, 
  android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
  android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, 
  android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
};

if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}
```

Comment: Hi James yes your solution works perfect !!! Many thanx again ! just changed DeviceUtils.Hasmarshmallow()  to (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)  . I think this is better

Comment: It solved my problem too, thank you. @Frank if this solved your problem, don't forget to accept this answer so everybody can quickly see it.

Comment: What will be the value of `PERMISSION_ALL` in the above code?

Comment: It's an integer constant used to identify the request in the callback. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html

Comment: @JamesMcCracken thanks for the code .. but it always keep asking me for permission, doesn't matters whether I already granted or not.

Comment: @maveň I am facing the same problem.. If I do not grant 1 of them, it will ask all permissions again including others that I already granted.

Comment: I like the way this has been written. But can you show how you are handling multiple results in the onRequestPermissionsResult() method.

Comment: @JamesMcCracken hi using this code first time code run perfectly, but after restart app it fail while checking permission Code like this

Comment: Great solution! Although, I'm curious if API version check is really needed? I think if it's pre-Marshmallow OS permissions are granted on installation and then there's simply no reason to check the version.

Comment: This is a tidy solution. I've taken out the version check (@AlexBerdnikov is correct). However, I've noticed that when asking for multiple permissions the "don't ask again" check box is replaced with a counter (1 of 3... 2 of 3 etc). Just an observation.

Comment: Nice one, @JamesMcCracken. Thanks. I only had to add "android." to "Manifest. ..."

Comment: How to handle when user blocks one request ?

Comment: Nice one! @JamesMcCracken

Comment: Hi, is there a way to have multiple request codes? Like if we wanted different behavior based on grant/refuse for the different permissions we request?

Comment: Very nice! Below I put a answer with Kotlin equivalent code.

Comment: Thank you, i have applied the code to my app. Works fine, thanks once more!!!

Comment: Type mismatch on `(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Note for using with Kotlin:
You should call hasPermissions(...)  method with " * " symbol like this:
(!hasPermissions(this, *PERMISSIONS))

Answer (score 110):

**Here is detailed example with multiple permission requests:-**

The app needs 2 permissions at startup . SEND_SMS and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (both are mentioned in manifest.xml).

I am using **Support Library v4** which is  prepared to handle Android pre-Marshmallow and so no need to check build versions.

As soon as the app starts up, it asks for multiple permissions together. If both permissions are granted the normal flow goes.

[image]

[image]

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        // carry on the normal flow, as the case of  permissions  granted.
    }
}

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(), ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(), ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() are part of support library.**

In case one or more permissions are not granted, ActivityCompat.requestPermissions() will request permissions and the  control goes to onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method.

You should check the value of shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() flag in onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method.

**There are only two cases:--**

**Case 1:**-Any time user clicks Deny permissions (including the very first time), it will return true.  So when the user denies, we can show more explanation and keep asking again

**Case 2:**-Only if user select “never asks again” it will return false. In this case, we can continue with limited functionality and guide user to activate the permissions from settings for more functionalities, or we can finish the setup, if the permissions are trivial for the app.

**CASE -1**

[image]

**CASE-2**

[image]

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission callback called-------");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

                Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
                // Initialize the map with both permissions
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                // Fill with actual results from user
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                        perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                    // Check for both permissions
                    if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                            && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "sms & location services permission granted");
                        // process the normal flow
                        //else any one or both the permissions are not granted
                    } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Some permissions are not granted ask again ");
                            //permission is denied (this is the first time, when "never ask again" is not checked) so ask again explaining the usage of permission
//                        // shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return true
                            //show the dialog or snackbar saying its necessary and try again otherwise proceed with setup.
                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) || ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                                showDialogOK("SMS and Location Services Permission required for this app",
                                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                switch (which) {
                                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                                        checkAndRequestPermissions();
                                                        break;
                                                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                                        // proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                            //permission is denied (and never ask again is  checked)
                            //shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale will return false
                            else {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                        .show();
    //                            //proceed with logic by disabling the related features or quit the app.
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void showDialogOK(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Comment: but its showing all permission dialogs multiple times

Comment: You say "You should check the value of shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() flag in onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method. "   but https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html  advises to call shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale() before requesting permissions.  I am confused. Your code looks more reasonable but you never know with Google...

Comment: Thanks Nick, how to do  sequential permission popup? please guide me to fix this issue

Comment: dear all why i keep got error in this cannot resolve symbol : REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS

Comment: this answer is better than Google documentation, well done!

Comment: @AhmedSamir you need to define REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS eg. int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 100;

Answer (score 56):

Small code :

```
 public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 10; // code you want.

 String[] permissions= new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};


if (checkPermissions())
         //  permissions  granted.    
}

private  boolean checkPermissions() {
        int result;
        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p:permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissionsList[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:{
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                String permissionsDenied = "";
                for (String per : permissionsList) {
                    if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                        permissionsDenied += "\n" + per;

                    } 

                }
                // Show permissionsDenied 
                updateViews();
            }
                return;
            }
        }
     }
```

[List of Android permissions normal permissions and dangerous permissions in API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937109/1770868)

Comment: I know this is quite late, but just for anyone coming here: is that ok to always check `grantResults[0]` at index 0, even for futher items in `permissionsList`? Shouldn't `permissionsList` and `grantResults` be considered as side-by-side arrays?

Comment: what is update views?? here

Answer (score 11):

> In a Fragment

```
public class Homefragment extends Fragment {
    View hfrag;
   Context context;
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

//first we must check the permissions are already granted

        hfrag = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
        context = getActivity();
checkAndRequestPermissions();

}




}


private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
        int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        int contactpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);

        int writepermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        int callpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);

        int receivepermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
        int locationpermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (locationpermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

        if (contactpermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
        }
        if (writepermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
        if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        }
        if (receivepermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
        }

        if (callpermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            requestPermissions(listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }



 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);


    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {


        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {


                if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("msg", "accounts granted");
                        
                    }
                } else if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("msg", "storage granted");
                        
                    }
                } else if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("msg", "call granted");
                        
                    }
                } else if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("msg", "sms granted");
                        
                    }
                } else if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.e("msg", "location granted");
                        
                    }
                }


            }

        }


    }
}


}
```

Answer (score 7):

**It's easy, do this way**

```
private static final int REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 110 , REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 111, REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE = 112;
```

In your onCreate

```
 //request permission
    boolean hasPermissionPhoneState = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermissionPhoneState) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }

    boolean hasPermissionLocation = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermissionLocation) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    boolean hasPermissionWrite = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    if (!hasPermissionWrite) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE);
    }
```

Then check result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The app was not allowed to get your phone state. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        case REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The app was not allowed to get your location. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        case REQUEST_WRITE_STORAGE: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Permission granted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //reload my activity with permission granted or use the features what required the permission
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            } else
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The app was not allowed to write to your storage. Hence, it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it this permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.. just a question, can we disable touch events oustide alert dialogs when these alert dialogs appear. Because in my case I want the users to allow permissions and then only access the app.

Comment: @YogeshPatel  Anytime dude..  when these alert dialogs appear, the outside touch is automatically desabled except the **Status bar**.  then you only have two options - DENY or ALLOW. Don't forget to add all permissions to your Main activity.

You can hide the status bar, check this [Hiding the Status Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html)

Answer (score 7):

**NEW EASY AND CLEAN WAY OF ASKING MULTIPLE PERMISSIONS IN 2022**

At the top of your activity class, write

```
private val multiplePermissionContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissionsStatusMap ->
    // permissionStatusMap is of type <String, Boolean>
    // if all permissions accepted
    if (!permissionsStatusMap.containsValue(false)) {

        // All persmissions are accepted, do here whatever you want 

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "all permissions not accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

And, launch the permission asking dialogs whenever you want like below(for now, I am thinking that you need to ask the permissions when you click on xyzButton)

```
    xyzButton.setOnClickListener {
        multiplePermissionContract.launch(
            arrayOf(
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, 
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, 
                android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
                android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, 
                android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
            )
        )
    }
```

**NOTE -**

- registerForActivityResult() method will always be called whenever we click on xyzButton. If all any of the all permissions is not accepted earlier, it will ask that particular permission again; else it will directly execute the if condition block.

Answer (score 6):

My approach is based on Nicks' answer and hopefully is a bit more usable for multiple (as many as needed, not only two) permissions.
It suggests adding single-responsibility PermissionsHelper class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class PermissionsHelper {

private static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 100; // any code you want.

public void checkAndRequestPermissions(Activity activity, String... permissions) {
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(permission);
        }
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

            for (String permission : permissions) {
                perms.put(permission, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            }

            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                    perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);

                boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
                for (String permission1 : permissions) {
                    allPermissionsGranted = allPermissionsGranted && (perms.get(permission1) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }

                if (allPermissionsGranted) {
                    Log.d(PermissionsHelper.class.getSimpleName(), "onRequestPermissionsResult: all permissions granted");
                } else {
                    for (String permission2 : perms.keySet())
                        if (perms.get(permission2) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                            perms.remove(permission2);

                    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("The app has not been granted permissions:\n\n");
                    for (String permission : perms.keySet()) {
                        message.append(permission);
                        message.append("\n");
                    }
                    message.append("\nHence, it cannot function properly." +
                            "\nPlease consider granting it this permission in phone Settings.");

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                    builder.setTitle(R.string.permission_required)
                            .setMessage(message)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, (dialog, id) -> dialog.cancel());
                    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                    alert.show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

If one or several required permissions have not been granted by user, the detailed AlertDialog message will be shown to him.

Example of usage in Activity:

```
private PermissionsHelper permissionsHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checkPermissions();

    //any other code
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    permissionsHelper.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

private void checkPermissions() {
    permissionsHelper = new PermissionsHelper();
    permissionsHelper.checkAndRequestPermissions(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
}
```

Comment: Nice and neat solution. Helper class helps to unclutter main code.

Comment: @Andrew Vovk, this is great. How do you handle alternative user reponses e.g Allow for Location and Deny for Storage? I am getting this error on testing an Allow and Deny 'FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }}'

Answer (score 6):

My handler class for request multiple permissions. You can check the [full using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45953930/5381331) here

```
public class RequestPermissionHandler {
    private Activity mActivity;
    private RequestPermissionListener mRequestPermissionListener;
    private int mRequestCode;

    public void requestPermission(Activity activity, @NonNull String[] permissions, int requestCode,
            RequestPermissionListener listener) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mRequestCode = requestCode;
        mRequestPermissionListener = listener;

        if (!needRequestRuntimePermissions()) {
            mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
            return;
        }
        requestUnGrantedPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }

    private boolean needRequestRuntimePermissions() {
        return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M;
    }

    private void requestUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions, int requestCode) {
        String[] unGrantedPermissions = findUnGrantedPermissions(permissions);
        if (unGrantedPermissions.length == 0) {
            mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mActivity, unGrantedPermissions, requestCode);
    }

    private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mActivity, permission)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private String[] findUnGrantedPermissions(String[] permissions) {
        List<String> unGrantedPermissionList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (!isPermissionGranted(permission)) {
                unGrantedPermissionList.add(permission);
            }
        }
        return unGrantedPermissionList.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
            @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == mRequestCode) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
                    if (grantResult != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                mRequestPermissionListener.onSuccess();
            } else {
                mRequestPermissionListener.onFailed();
            }
        }
    }

    public interface RequestPermissionListener {
        void onSuccess();

        void onFailed();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a java example

Answer (score 6):

Refer this link for full understand of multiple permission, also full source code download, [click Here](https://codingmitra.com/multiple-permission-run-time-in-android/)

```
   private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int permissionReadPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    int permissionProcessOutGogingCalls = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
    int permissionProcessReadContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    int permissionProcessReadCallLog = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);

    int permissionWriteStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permissionReadStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (permissionReadPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
    if (permissionProcessOutGogingCalls != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
    }
    if (permissionProcessReadContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    if (permissionProcessReadCallLog != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG);
    }
    if (permissionWriteStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (permissionReadStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults == null) {
        /*If result is null*/
    } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        /*If We accept permission*/
    } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        /*If We Decline permission*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following methodology is about

- asking permissions dynamically ;
- showing a AlertDialog if the user denies any permission
- looping until the user accepts permission(s)

**Create a "static" class for permissions methods**

```
public class PermissionsUtil {
    public static final int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;

    public static boolean doesAppNeedPermissions(){
        return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1;
    }

    public static String[] getPermissions(Context context)
            throws PackageManager.NameNotFoundException {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        return info.requestedPermissions;
    }

    public static void askPermissions(Activity activity){
        if(doesAppNeedPermissions()) {
            try {
                String[] permissions = getPermissions(activity);

                if(!checkPermissions(activity, permissions)){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions,
                            PERMISSION_ALL);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkPermissions(Context context, String... permissions){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null &&
                permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) !=
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**In MainActivity.java**

```
    private void checkPermissions(){
        PermissionsUtil.askPermissions(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionsUtil.PERMISSION_ALL: {

                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    List<Integer> indexesOfPermissionsNeededToShow = new ArrayList<>();

                    for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length; ++i) {
                        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permissions[i])) {
                            indexesOfPermissionsNeededToShow.add(i);
                        }
                    }

                    int size = indexesOfPermissionsNeededToShow.size();
                    if(size != 0) {
                        int i = 0;
                        boolean isPermissionGranted = true;

                        while(i < size && isPermissionGranted) {
                            isPermissionGranted = grantResults[indexesOfPermissionsNeededToShow.get(i)]
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                            i++;
                        }

                        if(!isPermissionGranted) {

                            showDialogNotCancelable("Permissions mandatory",
                                    "All the permissions are required for this app",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            checkPermissions();
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showDialogNotCancelable(String title, String message,
                                         DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .create()
                .show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with answers asking for multiple permissions but multiple permission result code is not implemented very elegantly and may cause checking wrong permission result.

`if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)` is terrible logic for checking multiple permissions result, i don't know why Google implemented such a terrible code.

It's a mess especially when you check multiple permissions. Let say you ask for `CAMERA`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

You need to check for `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` but user only granted `CAMERA` at first run and you check for `grantResults[1]` but in second run `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` becomes the permission with index 0. I got so many problems with user not granting all permissions at once and have to write so pointless permission result logic.

You should either use

```
   int size = permissions.length;
    boolean locationPermissionGranted = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (permissions[i].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationPermissionGranted = true;
        }
    }
```

Or simpler one

```
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // Do something ...
        }
```

in `onPermissionRequestResult` method.

Answer (score 3):

**Checking every situation**

if denied - showing Alert dialog to user why we need permission

```
public static final int MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
public static final int CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 2;
public static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;

    private void askPermissions() {

    int permissionCheckStorage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    int permissionCheckCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA); 

   // we already asked for permisson & Permission granted, call camera intent
    if (permissionCheckStorage == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionCheckCamera == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        launchCamera();

    } //asking permission for the first time
     else if (permissionCheckStorage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && permissionCheckCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);

    } else {
        // Permission denied, so request permission

        // if camera request is denied
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("You need to give permission to take pictures in order to work this feature.");
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("GIVE PERMISSION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    // Show permission request popup
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }   // if storage request is denied
                else if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("You need to give permission to access storage in order to work this feature.");
            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("GIVE PERMISSION", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();

                    // Show permission request popup
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        } 

    }
}
```

**Checking Permission Results**

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                // check whether camera permission granted or not.
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    launchCamera();
                }
            }
            break;
        case STORAGE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // check whether storage permission granted or not.
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    launchCamera();
                }
            }
            break;
        case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) && permissions[1].equals(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                // check whether All permission granted or not.
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    launchCamera();

                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

> you can just copy and paste this code, it works fine. change context(this) & permissions according to you.

Answer (score 2):

Short and sweet :). what I believe in.

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}; // List of permissions required

public void askPermission()
{
    for (String permission : PERMISSIONS) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
            return;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:{
            if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                //Do your work.
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Until you grant the permission, we cannot proceed further", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After seeing all the long and complex answers. I want post this answer.

[**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) is widely used library now for asking permission in one line code.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions
.request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
         Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) {
       // All requested permissions are granted
    } else {
       // At least one permission is denied
    }
});
```

add in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

**Isn't this easy?**

Comment: This is very easy, but if CAMERA allowed I want to do something and READ_PHONE_STATE is not allowed I want to do something else. How can I handle multiple different situation?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully implemented simple code for Multiple permission at Once.
Follow the below steps
1:Make Utility.java class like below

```
public class Utility {
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 123;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
public static boolean checkPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, permission)) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

2: Now call

```
boolean permissionCheck = Utility.checkPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS);
```

in your Activity onCreate() or according to your logic.

3:Now check permission before performing operation for particular task

```
if (permissionCheck) {
 performTaskOperation();//this method what you need to perform
} else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Need permission ON.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
```

4: Now implement onRequestPermissionsResult() method in your Activity as below

```
  @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (userChoosenTask.equals("STORAGE"))
                    performTaskOperation();//this method what you need to perform
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **I just use an array to achieved multiple requests, hope it helps someone. (Kotlin)**

```
    // got all permission
    private fun requestPermission(){
        var mIndex: Int = -1
        var requestList: Array<String> = Array(10, { "" } )

        // phone call Permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mIndex ++
            requestList[mIndex] = Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
        }
        // SMS Permission
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mIndex ++
            requestList[mIndex] = Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS
        }

        // Access photos Permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mIndex ++
            requestList[mIndex] = Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }

        // Location Permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mIndex ++
            requestList[mIndex] = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        }

        if(mIndex != -1){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, requestList, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ALL)
        }
    }


    // permission response
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int,
                                            permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ALL -> {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // permission accept location
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Phone Call permission accept.")
                    }

                    // permission accept location
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SMS permission accept.")
                    }

                    // permission accept location
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "SMS permission accept.")
                    }

                    // permission accept location
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Location permission accept.")
                    }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Permission Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
private val id = 1
private val permissions = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
fun hasPermissions(): Boolean {
 for (perm in permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false
                }
            }

        return true
    }

    if(! hasPermissions()){
                   requestPermissions(this, permissions, id)
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this is in the runtime permissions example from Google's github.

```
 private static String[] PERMISSIONS_CONTACT = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS};
private static final int REQUEST_CONTACTS = 1;
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_CONTACT, REQUEST_CONTACTS);
```

Comment: Hi Owls thanx but this is not my question.  I want call 4 different permission at the same time from 4 permission groups. Call them all together so the user can activate them all in one step ..one google app makes the same possible

Comment: ...no sorry Owls ..got it know ..i think you are right ! Will try this out thanx

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Asking for multiple permissions at a time" section in this article:

[Things you need to know about Android M permissions](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

It's very well explained, and may also touch other related topics you haven't think about.

Answer (score 0):

Use helper like this (permissions names do not matter).

```
public class MyPermission {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL = 127;
private MainActivity mMainActivity;

MyPermission(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    mMainActivity = mainActivity;
}

public static boolean hasPermission(String permission, Context context) {
    if (isNewPermissionModel()) {
        return (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (isNewPermissionModel() && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private static boolean shouldShowRationale(Activity activity, String permission) {
    return isNewPermissionModel() && ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission);
}

private static boolean isNewPermissionModel() {
    return VERSION.SDK_INT > VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1;
}


/**
 * check all permissions
 */
void checkAll() {
    //check dangerous permissions, make request if need (Android will ask only for the ones it needs)
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            permission.READ_CALENDAR,           
            permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION   
    };

    if (!hasPermissions(mMainActivity, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mMainActivity, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL);
    }
}

void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_ALL) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0) {
            //for not granted
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {

                if (permissions[i].equals(permission.READ_CALENDAR)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        smartRequestPermissions(permission.READ_CALENDAR, R.string.permission_required_dialog_read_calendar);
                    }
                } else if (permissions[i].equals(permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        smartRequestPermissions(permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, R.string.permission_required_dialog_access_coarse_location);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

private void smartRequestPermissions(final String permissionName, int permissionRequiredDialog) {
    if (shouldShowRationale(mMainActivity, permissionName)) {// If the user turned down the permission request in the past and chose the Don't ask again option in the permission request system dialog, this method returns false.

        //Show an explanation to the user with action
        mMainActivity.mSnackProgressBarManager.show(
                new SnackProgressBar(
                        SnackProgressBar.TYPE_ACTION, mMainActivity.getString(permissionRequiredDialog)
                )
                        .setAction("OK", new OnActionClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onActionClick() {
                                checkAll();
                            }
                        })
                        .setSwipeToDismiss(true).setAllowUserInput(true)
                , MainActivity.SNACKBAR_WARNING_DURATION
        );

    } // else do nothing
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to ask multiple permission,

https://github.com/sachinvarma/EasyPermission

How to add :

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

implementation 'com.github.sachinvarma:EasyPermission:1.0.1'
```

How to ask permission:

```
 List<String> permission = new ArrayList<>();
 permission.add(EasyPermissionList.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
 permission.add(EasyPermissionList.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

 new EasyPermissionInit(MainActivity.this, permission);
```

For more Details - >

https://github.com/sachinvarma/EasyPermission/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/sachinvarma/easypermissionsample/MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have done in my activity. I am asking for camera and microphone permissions.

```
public class ActiveCallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    .....
    
    private static final String cameraPermissionKey = "cameraPermission";
    private static final String microphonePermissionkey = "microphonePermission";

    private static ArrayList<String> permissionsQueue = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        .....
        // in ValidationCheckersAndValidators simply checking if have permission or not.
        if(ValidationCheckersAndValidators.haveCameraPermission(this)) performHaveCameraPermissionLayout(); else performHaveNoCameraPermissionLayout();
        if(ValidationCheckersAndValidators.haveMicrophonePermission(this)) performHaveMicrophonePermissionLayout(); else performHaveNoMicrophonePermissionLayout();

    }

    private void performHaveNoCameraPermissionLayout() {
        .....
        permissionsQueue.add(cameraPermissionKey);
    }

    private void performHaveNoMicrophonePermissionLayout() {
        .....
        permissionsQueue.add(microphonePermissionkey);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        .....
        passThroughPermissionsQueue();
    }

    private void passThroughPermissionsQueue() {
        if(!permissionsQueue.isEmpty()) {
            String permissionKey = permissionsQueue.remove(0);
            switch (permissionKey) {
                case cameraPermissionKey: {
                    ValidationCheckersAndValidators.requestForCameraPermission(this);
                    return;
                }
                case microphonePermissionkey: {
                    ValidationCheckersAndValidators.requestForMicrophonePermission(this);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch(requestCode) {
            case cameraPermissionRequestCode: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    performHaveCameraPermissionLayout();
                }
                break;
            }
            case microphonePermissionRequestCode: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    performHaveMicrophonePermissionLayout();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        passThroughPermissionsQueue();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dexter](https://github.co/Karumi/Dexter)

In `build.gradle` add:

```
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
```

And use it in your activity as:

```
val requiredPermissions = when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q -> listOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)
            else -> listOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
        }

Dexter.withActivity(this)
     .withPermissions(
           requiredPermissions
      )
     .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
        override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
             permissions: MutableList<PermissionRequest>?,
                    token: PermissionToken?
             ) {
                    /* ... */
                }


        override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport) = 
             if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied) {
                toast("You should grant all permissions") 
             } else {
                toast("All permissions granted")

                // continue here if permission is a must

              }).check()

             // continue here if permission is not a must
```