# In Marshmallow, how to prompt two or more permissions dialog one by one like Hangouts does?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I'm handling my application code to work in **Marshmallow** devices, I'm managing its permissions dialog to show in needed places.

Currently held up with this scenario where it required two permission **(Location and Storage)** and I want to ask one by one like how Hangout does. Couldn't find how it's customized, any solution?

[image]
[image]

Here is the code I handle for single permission:

```
case REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {

    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        /Permission is granted
        Toast.makeText(this, "SDK >= 23 & permission Granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;

    } else {
        //Permission is revoked
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`:

```
case REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {

    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // permission was granted, yay! Do the
        // contacts-related task you need to do.
        Log.e("PMS", "granted");
        Toast.makeText(this, "SDK >= 23 & permission Granted ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        Log.e("PMS", "Not Granted");

        // permission denied, boo! Disable the
        // functionality that depends on this permission.
        int checkStatus = getPermissionStatus(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (checkStatus == 3) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SDK  >= 23 & permission Denied ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (checkStatus == 4) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "SDK  >= 23 & permission Blocked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For requesting multiple permission one by one you need to add all permission in second parameter `String[]`  `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` method. Like this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Thanks for your time. @Sagar Trehan

Answer (score 1):

Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495855/403255 for detailed answer. I've added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to @nicks answer.

```
public static final int REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_ID = 456;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if(checkAndRequestPermissions()) {
        // TODO - all permissions granted already
    }
}

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {
    int permissionSendMessage = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (permissionSendMessage != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_ID);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for link will check it

Answer (score 0):

I use a permission util for this:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;



/**
 * Permission Utils
 */
public final class PermissionUtils {

    public static final String PER_READ_PHONE_STATE = Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE;
    public static final String PER_GET_ACCOUNTS = Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS;
    public static final String PER_WAKE_LOCK = Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK;
    public static final String FEEDBACK_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1001;


    private PermissionUtils() {
    }

    public static boolean checkPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (!checkPermission(context, permission)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean AllPermissionsGranted(Context context) {
        return IsAccountsInfoGranted(context) && IsDeviceInfoGranted(context);
    }

    public static boolean checkPermission(Context context, String permission) {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    //define functions for each permission
    public static boolean IsWakeLockGranted(Context context) {
        return checkPermission(context, PER_WAKE_LOCK);
    }

    public static boolean IsAccountsInfoGranted(Context context) {
        return checkPermission(context, PER_GET_ACCOUNTS);
    }

    public static boolean IsDeviceInfoGranted(Context context) {
        return checkPermission(context, PER_READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }

    public static boolean PermissionsGranted(@NonNull int[] permissionResults) {
        if (permissionResults.length > 0) {
            for (int permission : permissionResults) {
                if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

    public static void RequestPermissions(Activity activity, int permissionId, String... permissions) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permissions, permissionId);
    }
}
```

use this code to request permissions in wherever you want :

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{PermissionUtils.PER_GET_ACCOUNTS, PermissionUtils.PER_READ_PHONE_STATE};
PermissionUtils.RequestPermissions(Act_Launch.this, PermissionUtils.FEEDBACK_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, permissions);
```

And this method in activity to handle the app permission or denial

```
    /***************************************
     * RequestPermissionResult
     ***************************************/
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PermissionUtils.PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (PermissionUtils.PermissionsGranted(grantResults)) {
                    ShowRegistrationView();
                } else {
                   //Do Whatever you want
                }
                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to send several permissions at the same time in an array.
I recommend you to use [PermissionHelper](https://github.com/k0shk0sh/PermissionHelper) or [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher) libraries.
Then you can just request it like this:

```
permissionHelper
     .setForceAccepting(false)// true if you had like force reshowing the permission dialog on Deny (not recommended)
     .request(MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS_ARRAY);
```

I hope it helps!