# How to Give Multiple permissions at once in Runtime android M at my code

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I want to grant multiple permissions at once..... This is my code.. this is just sample I want to Give Multiple permissions at once..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final int R_PERM = 123;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.data);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    if ((CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA))&&
         (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))&&
         (CheckPermission(this, Manifest.permission.NFC)))
    {
        PermHandling();
    }

    else {
        RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, R_PERM);
        RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, R_PERM );
        RequestPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.NFC, R_PERM );

        //NewPermHandling();
    }

}
private void PermHandling() {
    //My app internal parts....
    //Here my stuff works...
}

//private void NewPermHandling(){

//}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int permsRequestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (permsRequestCode) {

        case R_PERM: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                PermHandling();
            } else {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Please Grant Permissions other wise app will close.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void RequestPermission(Activity thisActivity, String Permission, int Code) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Permission)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
                Permission)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                    new String[]{Permission},
                    Code);
        }
    }
}

public boolean CheckPermission(Context context, String Permission) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Here I have Given permissions one by one So I am getting Permissions one by one at Run time Please suggest me to Give all permissions at once..

Please suggest me on my code where should I need to change..

here I my App I have more permissions I need to give at once like camera,location,storage etc... Please suggest me on Mycode....

**Update**
and all permissions should be at once  with ***Never Ask again*** check button....

Please suggest me of this kind in my code,,,,

Comment: Can any one correct my code in your Answer... I am new to this Permissions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 6.0 multiple permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions)

Answer (score -1):

Inside your Request Permision method instead of sending one permission at a time you can ask for multiple using.

```
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Permission1,Permission2,Permission3},
                Code);
```

Where Permission1=Manifest.permission.CAMERA
Permission2= Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
Permission3=Manifest.permission.NFC

What this does is it makes android ask for permissions one after the other in dialog boxes. And you can check which permissions are granted all at once in your onRequestPermissionsResult by running through the int[] grantResults

Note that int[] grantResults returns permission grant result in the order of permissions asked. In our case - Manifest.permission.CAMERA
,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
Manifest.permission.NFC

Have a look at link below where it has been explained in detail.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score -1):

You can create permission array and pass it directly to `requestPermissions()`.

```
String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
```

and pass it to `requestPermissions()`

```
requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, 10);
```

and check whether you got all permission or not in `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            if (hasAllPermissionsGranted(grantResults)) {
                // Permission Granted

            } else {
                // Permission Denied

            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Here is `hasAllPermissionsGranted` method

```
public boolean hasAllPermissionsGranted(@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    for (int grantResult : grantResults) {
        if (grantResult == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For another approach to take care of multiple permission, check [Requesting Runtime Permission – Part 2](http://androidgig.com/requesting-runtime-permission-part-2/)

Comment: Yeah sure, mail me your project,  i will complete all your task :) We are here to help you, not to complete your project. We can give you code snippets but not whole code.

Comment: The Above one is my code sir... Please suggest me sir... My Project is Huge... and confidential... I am just one part of it,,, still I don't have of full code... sorry sir.... Please help me

Comment: @downvoter : thank you, but care to mention my mistake.