# ask multiple permission only once in single pop up on targetsdk 23

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I want to view pop up like OLA app for ask permission only one time to user(do not need more click for user ) .
I am using this example and no other concept or logic found out any where [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions/35495855#35495855)

Answer (score 0):

Android Runtime Permissions are categorized into two parts `Normal and Dangerous Permissions`

**Normal Permissions:** They Just to be added in manifest

**Dangerous Permissions:** They need to asked at runtime from user.

All dangerous Android system permissions belong to `permission groups.`

[image]

you can request a group permission and all permissions in a group will be granted in single click but if you need some permission from different groups then you will see different popups from system.

Hope you understand the structure.

Comment: so how to do this with ola app

Comment: @Essar kindly send ola app link.

Comment: ola app link for android -https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.olacabs.customer

Comment: have you any idea about this so plz let me know

Comment: @Essar sory dear cant be able to run because i have downgraded my OS version.