# How to ask multiple permissions at the same time in android 6.0+

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow

i want to ask the user to accept the following permissions at the same time(one by one), the permissions are like:
checkLocationPermission, checkReadSMS, checkCallingPermission, checkReadState, checkContactWriteState.
So, how i can ask all these permissions in my first screen itself.
Please help me out in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible.

Comment: Ya shabbir Dhangot, i think its possible, please help me out in this regard. thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you want it in one shot its not possible. This update is because user come to know that you want this permission for purpose. You can ask all permission onebyone. But single allow for all permission in 6.0 update is not possible.

Comment: ok shabbir dhangot, i need to ask permissions one by one in one screen itself, can you help me in this regard?

Comment: Do you mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/34343101/6774854

Comment: You can request multiple permission is a single request but multiple dialog pops-up, for more information https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/runtime-permissions-best-practices-and-how-to-gracefully-handle-permission-removal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first check that user phone build version is 23.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    askPermissions(true);
} else {
    startActivity(new Intent(PermissionsActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

If version is 23 then you need to ask permissions.

```
private void askPermissions(boolean isForOpen) {
    isRationale = false;
    List permissionsRequired = new ArrayList();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsRequired.add("Write External Storage");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE))
        permissionsRequired.add("Call phone");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))
        permissionsRequired.add("Read phone state");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        permissionsRequired.add("Read Contacts");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS))
        permissionsRequired.add("Receive SMS");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS))
        permissionsRequired.add("Get Accounts");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
        permissionsRequired.add("Location");
    if (!checkPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsRequired.add("Location");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0 && !isRationale) {
        if (permissionsRequired.size() > 0) {

        }
        if (isForOpen) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                        11);
            }
        }

    } else if (isRationale) {
        if (isForOpen) {

            new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle)
                    .setTitle("Permission Alert")
                    .setMessage("You need to grant permissions manually. Go to permission and grant all permissions.")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 123);
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
        }
    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(PermissionsActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}

private boolean checkPermission(List permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!isFirst) {
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, permission)) {
                    isRationale = true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

on the onRequestPermissionsResult you need to check which permissions granted

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 11:
            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            }
            // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    perms.get(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    perms.get(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // All Permissions Granted
                startActivity(new Intent(PermissionsActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
                finish();
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "Some Permission is Denied.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                isFirst = false;
                askPermissions(true);
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    }
}
```

If user has set the permission to never ask again then the application setting screen will open. User will allow/Deny permission there. You need to check again on the activityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    askPermissions(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!hasPermissions()){
                        // your app doesn't have permissions, ask for them.
                        requestNecessaryPermissions();
                    }
                    else {
                        // your app already have permissions allowed.
                        // do what you want.
                    }


private boolean hasPermissions() {
        int res = 0;
        // list all permissions which you want to check are granted or not.
        String[] permissions = new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        for (String perms : permissions){
            res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(perms);
            if (!(res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                // it return false because your app dosen't have permissions.
                return false;
            }

        }
        // it return true, your app has permissions.
        return true;
    }

    private void requestNecessaryPermissions() {
        // make array of permissions which you want to ask from user.
        String[] permissions = new String[] {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            // have arry for permissions to requestPermissions method.
            // and also send unique Request code.
            requestPermissions(permissions, REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMS);
        }
    }

    /* when user grant or deny permission then your app will check in
      onRequestPermissionsReqult about user's response. */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grandResults) {
        // this boolean will tell us that user granted permission or not.
        boolean allowed = true;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMS:
                for (int res : grandResults) {
                    // if user granted all required permissions then 'allowed' will return true.
                    allowed = allowed && (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
                }
                break;
            default:
                // if user denied then 'allowed' return false.
                allowed = false;
                break;
        }
        if (allowed) {
            // if user granted permissions then do your work.
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
        else {
            // else give any custom waring message.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Camera Permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Storage Permissions denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

follow this tutorial, in this tutorial multiples permissions are asked

[Android 6.0 Runtime Permissions](https://learnpainless.com/android/marshmallows/runtime-permission-example-good-practice-real-example)

Answer (score 0):

the **Kotlin** version

```
import android.Manifest
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MyFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    val TAG: String = MyFragment::class.java.simpleName
    var PERMISSIONS = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    )
}

private val permReqLauncher =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
        val granted = permissions.entries.all {
            it.value == true
        }
        if (granted) {
            displayCameraFragment()
        }
    }

private fun takePhoto() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        displayCameraFragment()
    }
    activity?.let {
        if (hasPermissions(activity as Context, PERMISSIONS)) {
            displayCameraFragment()
        } else {
            permReqLauncher.launch(
                PERMISSIONS
            )
        }
    }
}

// util method
private fun hasPermissions(context: Context, permissions: Array<String>): Boolean = permissions.all {
    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
}

private fun displayCameraFragment() {
    // open camera fragment
}
}
```