# Android runtime permission passes even if it doesn't have permission

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm developing an app on two different computers, and using github to sync the project using Android Studios git tools.
I can't get the permissions right after I ran my app from my secondary workstation.

It seems **ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()** returns **true** even if the app doesn't have the required permissions, which leads the app to skip the **ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()**  method.

Android Studio asks me to reinstall the app every time I switch workstations, as the signatures doesn't match or something. I assume the app might remember the old permissions even if it haven't gotten new ones?

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Why the hell is **ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission()**  returning true when I have no permissions?

I ask for all the permissions in my MainActivity in the oncreate() method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 123);
        Toast.makeText(this, "This app needs camera and storage permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        onCreateAfterPermission();
    }

}
```

I then handle the response:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if (requestCode == 123) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            onCreateAfterPermission();

        }else{
            // close the app
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry!!!, you can't use this app without granting permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem. or check define all the permission into android manifest file.

Comment: no need to ask runtime permission for `INTERNET`

Comment: share onCreateAfterPermission(); code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove following check from your if condition:

```
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

The above condition will be always evaluate to `false` since Internet permission is classified as normal permission and is granted at installation time.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
        Toast.makeText(this, "This app needs camera and storage permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        onCreateAfterPermission();
    }

}
```

One more thing, you should segregate the checking for `CAMERA` & `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. This is because, there could be case where `CAMERA` permission is granted but `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is not granted.

With your checking the condition will not satisfy hence `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` wont be asked.

Check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462424/how-to-ask-multiple-permissions-at-the-same-time-in-android-6-0) for implementation details for better approach.

Comment: It seems there is something fundamentally wrong with checking for multiple permissions at once. I implemented the code in your link, and now it works like a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

[AS per my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50943505/android-runtime-permission-passes-even-if-it-doesnt-have-permission/50943577?noredirect=1#comment88884465_50943505)

No need to ask runtime permission for `INTERNET` because it is granted at the time of app installation

**FYI**

Dangerous  permission are need to ask runtime from os  marshmallow and above

The  `INTERNET` is normal

For more information please check this post  [Normal permissions and dangerous permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936914/list-of-android-permissions-normal-permissions-and-dangerous-permissions-in-api)

Try this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
        Toast.makeText(this, "This app needs camera and storage permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        onCreateAfterPermission();
    }

}
```

to ask multiple runtime permission please check below post

- [Android 6.0 multiple permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions)
- [Ask Multiple Permissions Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467618/ask-multiple-permissions-android)
- [How to ask multiple permissions at the same time in android 6.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39462424/how-to-ask-multiple-permissions-at-the-same-time-in-android-6-0)
- [How to ask multiple permissions at same time in Android Marshmelllow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38582470/how-to-ask-multiple-permissions-at-same-time-in-android-marshmelllow)

Comment: you post same answer @Sagar just add some posts why?

Comment: @AD10 have u check the code just check again my friend you will find the difference

Comment: @AD10 we both have given ans at the same time just one min difference so you can not say that same answer

Comment: @AD10 you can also check edit history for both answer

Comment: @AD10 the time difference between these two answers is so minimal, so I don't think foul play can be assumed, going off the edit history, the code you both posted in each of the first revisions seems identical, I think its just a coincidence that you both posted the same code

Comment: This question/answers are [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369821/is-it-wrong-to-add-the-same-answer-that-another-user-posts-at-the-same-time).