# Android M : Ask multiple Runtime Group Permissions together

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I know how can i ask multiple permission at Runtime in android, and i am well aware about Group system in Runtime Permission Architecture.

I want to know if there is way allows to ask **multiple Group permissions together** as like multiple permissions at Runtime.

I want to ask Storage Group, Camera Group and Location Group permissions together.

Comment: This is repeated a question. Kindly review at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions)

Comment: dude i am talking about multiple group permissions @KrunalKapadiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not ask for rights to permission groups using the current runtime permission API. You ask for rights to *permissions*, not *permission groups*. At the moment, through Android 7.0, the way the *system* handles this is by asking the user to grant you rights to the associated permission groups. It may or may not do so in the future.

> I want to know if there is way allows to ask multiple Group permissions together as like multiple permissions at Runtime.

No. There is no way to ask for a single permission group, let alone multiple ones.

Answer (score 1):

As per current version of Android, there is no way to ask **multiple Group permissions together** as you want. There is other option possible is [this](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)