# How to ask permission to access gallery on android M.?

Tags: java, android

I have this app that will pick image to gallery and display it to the test using Imageview. My problem is it won't work on Android M. I can pick image but won't show on my test.They say i need to ask permission to access images on android M but don't know how. please help.

Answer (score 44):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

**Type 1-** When your app requests permissions, the system presents a dialog box to the user. When the user responds, the system invokes your app's onRequestPermissionsResult() method, passing it the user response. Your app has to override that method to find out whether the permission was granted. The callback is passed the same request code you passed to requestPermissions().

```
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 1;

ChoosePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(EditProfileActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EditProfileActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        } else {
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});


@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
       switch (requestCode) {
            case PICK_FROM_GALLERY:
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                  Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                  startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, PICK_FROM_GALLERY);
                } else {
                    //do something like displaying a message that he didn`t allow the app to access gallery and you wont be able to let him select from gallery
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Type 2-** If you want to give runtime permission back to back in one place then you can follow below link

[Android 6.0 multiple permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions)

And in Manifest add permission for your requirements

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

**Note-** If Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE produce error then please replace this with android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

**==>** If you want to know more about runtime permission then please follow below link

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

**-----------------------------UPDATE  1--------------------------------**

**Runtime Permission Using EasyPermissions**

EasyPermissions is a wrapper library to simplify basic system permissions logic when targeting Android M or higher.

**Installation**
Add dependency in App level gradle

```
 dependencies {
// For developers using AndroidX in their applications
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'

// For developers using the Android Support Library
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'
}
```

Your Activity (or Fragment) override the onRequestPermissionsResult method:

```
 @Override
     public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] 
    permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions,grantResults);

        // Forward results to EasyPermissions
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
    }
```

**Request Permissions**

```
private static final int LOCATION_REQUEST = 222;
```

**Call this method**

```
@AfterPermissionGranted(LOCATION_REQUEST)
private void checkLocationRequest() {
   String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perms)) {
        // Already have permission, do the thing
        // ...
    } else {
        // Do not have permissions, request them now
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this,"Please grant permission",
                LOCATION_REQUEST, perms);
    }
}
```

Optionally, for a finer control, you can have your Activity / Fragment implement the PermissionCallbacks interface.

**implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks**

```
 @Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been granted
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> list) {
    // Some permissions have been denied
    // ...
}
```

**Link ->** https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions

**-----------------------------UPDATE  2  For KOTLIN--------------------------------**

**Runtime Permission Using florent37**

**Installation** Add dependency in App level gradle

**dependency**

```
implementation 'com.github.florent37:runtime-permission-kotlin:1.1.2'
```

**In Code**

```
        askPermission(
        Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    ) {
       // camera or gallery or TODO
    }.onDeclined { e ->
        if (e.hasDenied()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage(getString(R.string.grant_permission))
                .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes)) { dialog, which ->
                    e.askAgain()
                } //ask again
                .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no)) { dialog, which ->
                    dialog.dismiss()
                }
                .show()
        }

        if (e.hasForeverDenied()) {
            e.goToSettings()
        }
    }
```

**Link->** https://github.com/florent37/RuntimePermission

Comment: You dont need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE if you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. WRITE includes READ.

Comment: @DileepPatel Sorry I kinda new to this. Where exactly would you place that java code? Also thank you for the answer

Comment: @TheincredibleJan According to caution block: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#perm-groups this may cause IOException in case these two permissions will be in separated groups in future Android versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pickFile() {
        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                CAMERA);
        if (permissionCheck != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    getActivity(),
                    new String[]{CAMERA},
                    PERMISSION_CODE
            );
            return;
        }
        openCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCamera();
            }
        }
    }

    private void openCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);
    }


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```