# ContextCompat not found

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I use the below in my code:

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
```

In my gradle I have:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
```

Everything was working fine and the builds were triggering, however suddenly my builds are failing with the below error:

```
 error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
```

in the import statement :`android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat`

Can someone please help out. Since this is happening on a build machine I dont have android studio in it.

Comment: Sid try to my answer for how to give run time permission hope this can help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866869/how-to-ask-permission-to-access-gallery-on-android-m/39866945#39866945

Comment: I get an error that ActivityCompat cant be found

Comment: please show your full app gradle file

Answer (score 0):

just use this

`Activity` and extend from `AppCompatActivity`.

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
```

Comment: how will that cause a difference? as in whats the reasoning behind this?

Answer (score 0):

Include this

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.1'
```