# ImageView.setImageURI() from sharedPreferences string won't load due to permissions error

Tags: android, imageview, sharedpreferences

I have a PreferenceFragment that implements a custom Preference that I've extended. It launches an intent that returns a selected image from the filesystem.
Everything works fine, mostly. The Preference sets the image thumbnail in the preferences view and grabs the display name to set as the preference summary. The URI string persists as it should. However, When the preference screen initializes, it fails to retrieve either the display name or the image resource due to a permissions error.

```
Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/125
     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{80311e3 16941:com.companyXXX.appnameXXX/u0a87} (pid=16941, uid=10087) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I can post the code if anyone wants it. I am sure I have pinpointed the problem, but I am not sure how to add permissions to the ImageView.setImageUri() resource access.

This is not a duplicate of [How to ask permission to access gallery on android M.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866869/how-to-ask-permission-to-access-gallery-on-android-m/39866945) as I have permissions for the initial file selection. THAT WORKS JUST FINE.

hoping someone out there is familiar with this issue and can provide a solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39866869/how-to-ask-permission-to-access-gallery-on-android-m/39866945

Answer (score 0):

> It launches an intent that returns a selected image from the filesystem.

Based on that `Uri`, you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or perhaps `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. Neither are limited to files on the filesystem.

> The URI string persists as it should

In general, you should not assume that a `Uri` is valid indefinitely. They work like URLs do, and while some URLs might work all the time, others are tied to valid user sessions or otherwise will break after some period of time.

> i am not sure how to add permissions to the resource access

If you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, you can call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on `ContentResolver` to request durable access to the content identified by the `Uri`. That `Uri` may still break (e.g., the user deletes the content), but you will be able to persist the `Uri` as you are doing.

Otherwise, you have no means of getting durable access to the content, except by making a copy of the content itself.

Comment: I am using ACTION_GET_CONTENT, here is the Intent setup:

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
          intent.setType("image/*");
          intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
          startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);

Comment: Is there a more appropriate Action for this implementation? or, can you somehow call takePersistablePermissions() on the intent?

Comment: Or, is there an altogether better way of storing an image locator as a preference?

Comment: @Eric: Neither `ACTION_PICK` nor `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` are guaranteed to return a `Uri` that you can use indefinitely, and neither support `takePersistableUriPermissions()`. `takePersistableUriPermissions()` is a method on `ContentResolver`, not `Intent`. The safest thing is for you to copy the image once the user chooses it, and use appropriate labels in your UI (e.g., "import" instead of "link"). Or, [use a file-chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35), to limit yourself to files on the filesystem, in which case you can persist the path.

Comment: Thank you very much I will explore this further and post updates