# How to add Multiple permissions in the permissions Request

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I would like to know how to add multiple permissions on a single request.  This is regarding the Marshmallow version of android.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an arraylist of permission required

```
 List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();
    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
```

// addPermission

```
private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LoginActivity.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LoginActivity.this, permission))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Similarly add all your permissions in array list.

```
// now request permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context,
                    permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I want to handle more permission by using method onRequestPersmissionResult I have one int code

Comment: @SonuKumar Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions/35495855#35495855