# Check the runtime permission of app in android device

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Following code snippet is what I am using in order to understand the permission set by the user as in newer android devices permissions can be tweaked for specific app from settings.

I want to alert a user to give permission to avoid app crashing But the following snippet is always returning true for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
//If authorisation not granted for camera
boolean permission = (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);


if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //ask for authorisation
    //Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.CAMERA, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
    }
    else
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
}
else
    try {
        //releasing camera if it's already in use
        releaseCamera();
        camera = Camera.open(camId);
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: *But the following snippet is always returning true for me* you have either granted already the permission or have a pre-marshmallow version of android on your device

Comment: I am using nexus 5 Marshmallow. I tried multiple times setting permission on and off. permission is always returned as true for me however the app crashes (when permission is not given)

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue because this feature is available only in api level 23 and above. I was compiling on 22.

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean permission = (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //ask for authorisation
    //Manifest.permission.CAMERA
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
        showExplanation("Permission Needed", "Rationale", Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
    }
    else
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
}
else{
    try {
        //releasing camera if it's already in use
        releaseCamera();
        camera = Camera.open(camId);
}catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}}   /////// put your else condition in braces
```

Comment: Code is useless without explanation

Comment: @Tim Castelijins i have just edited the posted code,it is pretty self explanatory

Comment: I can't find what you changed, please tell. And please explain why you changed it

Comment: ActivityCompat instead of ContextCompat , as only an activity can check for permissions . ty @Tim would make sure next time i provide explanation even for changes :)

Comment: check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context, java.lang.String)

Comment: @Tim i agree,please let me know if there is any difference between ContextCompat and ActivityCompat ..... as the permission model only works for me when i use the latter only

Comment: depends on the sdk version you use. ContextCompat can be used for 23+

Comment: offcorse,the permission model has been introduced from 23+ only, but still ActivityCompat works for me but not ContextCompat,why ? ......can u help me with the reason ? @ Tim