# How to check multiple permissions at multiple requests in Android?

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have a MainActivity where I perform multiple tasks. Each task requires different user permissions. In another Activity that I have, I ask the user for multiple permissions at a single request which I figured out how to do. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to ask for multiple permissions at multiple requests without having to write separate permission methods for each task? And if so, how would I go about this?

Comment: Your 2 questions are not related. You should ask them in different posts.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I feel like the second question is not worthy of a separate post. What do you think?

Comment: One question at the time it the questions are not related.

Comment: Hi you can use this code in link http://stackoverflow.com/a/37546500/1770868