# Not Able to Add Run time Permission on Above API level 23?

Tags: android, google-maps, runtime-permissions

I am not able to Show the exact position in the Google Map above 4.4.2 version.Still confused on where to add Run time permission?Please Help

GpsLocation class

```
public class GpsLocation extends Service implements LocationListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;
    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude
    double speed, direction;
    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GpsLocation(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        }




        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    if (isGPSEnabled) {




                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }


                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services



                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     */
    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GpsLocation.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public double getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will launch Settings Options
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            speed = location.getSpeed();
            direction = location.getBearing();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

NearMe class

```
public class NearMe extends Fragment {
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    GpsLocation gpsLocation;
    double longitude, latitude;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<MySchool> al_school = new ArrayList<MySchool>();
    ArrayList<MyCollege> al_college = new ArrayList<MyCollege>();
    ArrayList<MyUniversity> al_university = new ArrayList<MyUniversity>();

    private static final String TAG = NearMe.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String urlSchool = "http://www.**.com/api/v1/schools";
    private static final String urlCollege = "http://www.**.com/api/v1/colleges";
    private static final String urlUniversity = "http://www.**.com/api/v1/universities";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_near_me, container, false);

        final LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


        if (isConnected()) {
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "GPS is Enabled in your device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                mMapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
                mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                mMapView.onResume();

                try {
                    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                gpsLocation = new GpsLocation(getContext());


                if (gpsLocation.canGetLocation()) {
                    longitude = gpsLocation.getLongitude();
                    latitude = gpsLocation.getLatitude();

                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "latitude:" + latitude + "Longitude:" + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading…");
                pDialog.show();


                mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                        googleMap = mMap;

                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(gpsLocation.getLatitude(), gpsLocation.getLongitude()));
                        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14);
                        mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
                        mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

                        //  mMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);


                        //   LatLng schoollatlng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                        //   googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(schoollatlng).title("MyLocation"));
                        //   CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(schoollatlng).zoom(11).build();
                        //   googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        //   googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(gpsLocation.getLatitude(), gpsLocation.getLongitude()), 14.0f));

                        drawSchoolMarker();
                        drawCollegeMarker();
                        drawUniversityMarker();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
            }
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return v;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    private void hidePDialog() {
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }

    private void drawSchoolMarker() {

        JsonArrayRequest schoolRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(urlSchool,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                MySchool school = new MySchool();

                                school.setId(obj.getInt("id") + " ");
                                school.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                if (obj.getString("latitude") == "null") {
                                    school.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble("27.6712"));
                                } else {
                                    school.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("latitude")));
                                }

                                if (obj.getString("longitude") == "null") {
                                    school.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble("85.2865"));
                                } else {
                                    school.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("longitude")));
                                }

                                al_school.add(school);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        //iterate from arraylist
                        for (MySchool schoolItr : al_school) {

                            View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker, null);
                            TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.num_txt);
                            numTxt.setText(schoolItr.getName());
                            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(schoolItr.getLatitude(), schoolItr.getLongitude());
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(getContext(), marker))).title(schoolItr.getName()));
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(schoolRequest);
    }

    private void drawCollegeMarker() {
        JsonArrayRequest collegeRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(urlCollege,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                MyCollege college = new MyCollege();

                                college.setId("" + obj.getInt("id"));
                                college.setName("" + obj.getString("name"));
                                //college.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble("" + obj.getDouble("latitude")));
                                //college.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble("" + obj.getDouble("longitude")));
                                if (obj.getString("latitude") == "null") {

                                    college.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble("27.6712"));
                                } else {

                                    college.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("latitude")));
                                }

                                if (obj.getString("longitude") == "null") {
                                    college.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble("27.6712"));
                                } else {
                                    college.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("longitude")));

                                }

                                al_college.add(college);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        //iterate from arraylist
                        for (MyCollege collegeItr : al_college) {

                            View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_college, null);
                            TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.txt_college);
                            numTxt.setText(collegeItr.getName());
                            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(collegeItr.getLatitude(), collegeItr.getLongitude());
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(getContext(), marker))).title(collegeItr.getName()));
                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(collegeRequest);
    }

    private void drawUniversityMarker() {
        JsonArrayRequest uniRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(urlUniversity,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                MyUniversity university = new MyUniversity();

                                university.setId("" + obj.getInt("id"));
                                university.setName("" + obj.getString("name"));
                                //university.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble("" + obj.getDouble("latitude")));
                                //university.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble("" + obj.getDouble("longitude")));
                                if (obj.getString("latitude") == "null") {

                                    university.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble("27.6712"));
                                } else {

                                    university.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("latitude")));
                                }

                                if (obj.getString("longitude") == "null") {
                                    university.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble("27.6712"));
                                } else {
                                    university.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(obj.getString("longitude")));

                                }

                                al_university.add(university);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        //iterate from arraylist
                        for (MyUniversity universityItr : al_university) {

                            View marker = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custom_marker_university, null);
                            TextView numTxt = (TextView) marker.findViewById(R.id.txt_university);
                            numTxt.setText(universityItr.getName());
                            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(universityItr.getLatitude(), universityItr.getLongitude());
                            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(getContext(), marker))).title(universityItr.getName()));

                        }


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(uniRequest);
    }

    public static Bitmap createDrawableFromView(Context context, View view) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.measure(displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.layout(0, 0, displayMetrics.widthPixels, displayMetrics.heightPixels);
        view.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        view.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    private void showGPSDisabledAlertToUser() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("GPS is disabled in your device. Would you like to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Goto Settings Page To Enable GPS",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                            }
                        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Where is the exact issue?? and why the map is not displaying and above SDK 23?? version

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Try to this link it can help you  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions

Comment: By far i can just tell you are just checking the permission what if it not granted. Where are you requesting them? You should do that in activity before you access the getLocation method of your service.

Comment: @d1vivek681065 my gps location is taking latlng of 0,0 value

Comment: @seon that because you have no permission and its going to catch block. Just ask permission in your activity and on permission granted call getLocation method

Comment: in my Main Class or GPS Location Class?@d1vivek681065 can you please provide the useful link.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this piece of code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // this  says , Permissions are not granted , so ask for permissions here if not granted and look out for permission callback if user grants 
}
```

Comment: where i have to add this ??
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

       

    } else {

      

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

       
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

The code you probably copied from somewhere clearly even has a comment about how to do this.

You only *check* permissions but you never *request* them. Therefore you will never have permission for location.

See the Android documentation for more information about [`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request)

Comment: where i have to implement request permissions?

Comment: @seon Please read the code you've copied. There is a clear comment about this. Though even that is in a wrong place. Don't copy random code if you don't know what it even does. You'll get into trouble. Just read the documentation and it will explain what to do and where.

Comment: i know i have to add permission? but dont know where i have to place it? so its confusing me

Answer (score 1):

Override

```
 onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
```

method of your Activity and if permission is granted then do your Location based  work.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1):

You can request permission by following code

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MenuActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                    // permission wasn't granted
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MenuActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
                }
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MenuActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
                    // permission wasn't granted
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MenuActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONN);
                }
            }
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION) {
            if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted
            } else {
                // permission wasn't granted
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONN) {
            if (grantResults.length >= 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // permission was granted
            } else {
                // permission wasn't granted
            }
        }
    }
```

Add following attributes to your manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
```

Comment: i have referred this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ tutorial. so where i have to add this?? can you please tell in detail

Comment: to display map ,do you create project on https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library and [create credentials]

Comment: add permisson code in your activity in onCreate() method

Answer (score 1):

Above API level 23 you will be given permission pragmatically like:

Change SEND_SMS permission to your Google map permission

```
 private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

    Log.d("permission", "permission denied to SEND_SMS - requesting it");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS};

    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

}

Comment: how to check response of given permission like permission is granted or not :)

Comment: for that you have to use OnRequestPermissionResult override method

Answer (score 0):

Within the method getLocation.

---

```
 public Location getLocation() {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
//Do your thing
}
```

---

And to listen to the permission granted or denied override function onRequestPermissionsResult() in your activity/Fragment like this

---

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

---

Also the method you are using seems to be little bit old. Please checkout this link
https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever `getLocation()` methode calls and it always check for permission as per your code here

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    }
```

if permission not called means in manifest file you did not mention required permissions this could be the first check place if permission not given it wont call request permission

**Updated**
i have just checked that if you don't mention permission in `Manifest` file it wont ask for permission

Both will combine and ask for single permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>`

Add this two permission to `Manifest` file

Add this code to `getLocation()` method beginning

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((MainActivity.this), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQ_PERMISSION_CODE);
            return;
        }
    }
```

that's it until permission is given the method wont execute

*pardon my English

Comment: can you please provide some ueful link