# Null URI on API level >=23 camera intent

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-camera-intent, android-api-levels

This might be a possible duplicate but i can't seem to pinpoint the exact solution.
Camera works fine and returns the image uri on devices below api 23.
However app crushes right after capturing image on devices apove api 23 with log error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {ana.foodi/ana.foodi.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3940)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3983)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1548)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5765)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
                                                         at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:481)
                                                         at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:441)
                                                         at ana.foodi.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:672)
```

After checking with breakpoints,realised Uri (selectedImage) is null below:

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    final String filePath;
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && REQUEST_POST_PHOTO==999){


        if(requestCode == 2 ) {
            requestRuntimePermission();
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePaths = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePaths, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePaths[0]);
            filePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
```

I've tried requesting runtime permission with this

```
public void requestRuntimePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

but error persist.

startActivityForResult call

```
REQUEST_POST_PHOTO=999;
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CODE_POST);
```

Comment: You required only WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. You need to require all *dangerous* level permissions. On [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html) you have a *protection level* field for each permission.

Comment: "Camera works fine and returns the image uri on devices below api 23" -- you do not show your `startActivityForResult()` call. If you are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, it is not supposed to return a `Uri`, and few devices will have a camera app that does return a `Uri`.

Comment: @CommonsWare added

Answer (score 2):

You are using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not supposed to return a `Uri` via `onActivityResult()`. Instead, either:

- You provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, in which case the image is supposed to be saved to that location (see [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/Camera/FileProvider)), or
- You do not provide `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, in which case you get a thumbnail `Bitmap` back via the `"data"` extra on the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`

This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

Some buggy camera apps *will* return a `Uri`. Do not count on this behavior, as well-written camera apps will not.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE = 1000;
private String importFileName = "";

private void cameraIntent() {
    importFileName = getString(R.string.app_name) + new Random().nextInt();
    startActivityForResult(getCameraIntent(context, importFileName), REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE);
}

public Intent getCameraIntent(Context context, String fileName) {
    Intent chooserIntent = null;
    List<Intent> intentList = new ArrayList<>();
    Intent takePhotoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, context.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
    takePhotoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getExternalCacheDir(), fileName)));
    intentList = addIntentsToList(context, intentList, Collections.singletonList(takePhotoIntent));

    if (intentList.size() > 0) {
        String title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.choose);
        chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentList.remove(intentList.size() - 1), title);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentList.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    }
    return chooserIntent;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
            break;
    }
}

private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
    Uri imageUri;
    if (data == null) {
        imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalCacheDir(), importFileName));
    } else {
        imageUri = data.getData();
        if (imageUri == null)
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getExternalCacheDir(), importFileName));
    }
}
```

If you get permissions (camera, read/write external storage permissions) from user, this code snippet will work correctly. You can call cameraIntent().

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use both `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to read and write file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Here ask to write permission & read permission  add multiple permission

```
public void requestRuntimePermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Check this [Android 6.0 multiple permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions)

//Check permission granted or not if granted then call this block

```
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePaths = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePaths, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePaths[0]);
        filePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
        c.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for older versions, if multiple selection is allowed ([`Intent#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE)), URIs will be returned as clipboard data:

```
data.getClipData()
```

See [`Intent#getClipData()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getClipData()) and [`ClipData`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html).

Check if data is being returned there:

```
ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
Uri selectedImage = null;
if (clipData != null) {
    selectedImage = clipData.getItemAt(0).getUri();
} else {
    selectedImage = data.getData();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. clipdata is also null

Answer (score 0):

```
 targetSdkVersion 21
 change your targetsdk version in build.gradle to marshmallow it will be solved.
```

Comment: tried it but issue persist

Comment: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en 

Follow this link it will help you .