# My app from the Play Store hangs after modifying compileSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-library, android-sdk-tools

I have an app published in the Play store. I updated the compileSDKVersion and targetSDKVersion to 27. After the update was released, it did work for some but did not work for most users.

I tried to switch back and forth these compile and target and versions. However, on testing on the device it works but it does not work when I release it in the Play Store.

Which versions I have been using:

1. `compileSDKVersion = 18`, `targetSDKVersion = 18` (Worked, it was like this originally)
2. `compileSDKVersion = 27`, `targetSDKVersion = 27` (worked for some after updating but downloading it as a new app didn't work)
3. `compileSDKVersion = 18`, `targetSDKVersion = 18` (Couldn't even release)
4. `compileSDKVersion = 23`, `targetSDKVersion = 23` (Was able to release but still doesn't work, when I update the currently installed app, or when I install it as a new app)

Dependencies (In the current version):

- `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+'`
- `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'`
- `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`

Looking for an advice to solve this issue, really stuck!

Thanks very much!

Comment: are you getting any error when you try to upload that apk to play store?

Comment: @GaneshKalal not any error if I stuck to sdk version 23 or higher, otherwise I received error that I couldn't release because of target version.. bla bla.. didn't copy the note.

Comment: can you post the exact error

Comment: the hanging could of many reasons. It's hard to point out that error like this

Comment: The error is that I cannot open the app, it is just stuck at the splash screen. There is no other error

Comment: Looks like you didn't add the RunTime Permission Request in your code, since it wasn't necessary prior to MarshMallow.

Comment: @KlingKlang what is that and how can I add these permissions?

Comment: They were added in Marshmallow, just to amuse us developers a little more... Mind to do some research?

Comment: here you go https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you haven't made the permissions changes necessary when targeting SDK >=23 (Android 6.0).

See the documentation at https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: This was, in fact, the issue. Solved now! This link here was also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions