# Splashscreen with runtime permissions

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I have a splash screen on launching my app. So when showing the splash screen run time permission should show. I got this code below from github. But runtime permissions are not showing. Splash screen works fine, but runtime permission is not working when add this code below. I have added permissions read sms, read external storage, access location. I have given all these permissions in the manifest file also.

```
    public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



String loginstatus;
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashfile);


    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override

        public void run() {

            Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);

            startActivity(i);

            finish();

        }

    }, 3000);

    /*     Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Thread will sleep for 10 seconds
                sleep(4*1000);

                startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this,HomeActivity.class));


                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    // start thread
    background.start();*/
}

private void permissioncheck() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE))
        permissionsNeeded.add("READ");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("COURLOC");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("FINELOC");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("SMS");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                                // Marshmallow+
                                requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);


                            } else {
                                // Pre-Marshmallow
                            }

                        }
                    });
            return;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            // Marshmallow+
            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);


        } else {
            // Pre-Marshmallow

        }

        return;
    }else
    {
        // Toast.makeText(this,"Permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LaunchApp();
    }

    //insertDummyContact();
}


private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {

    Boolean cond;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        // Marshmallow+
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissionsList.add(permission);
            // Check for Rationale Option
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
                //  return false;

                cond = false;
        }
        //  return true;

        cond = true;


    } else {
        // Pre-Marshmallow
        cond = true;
    }

    return cond;

}

private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == 23) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Needed To Run The App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {
        Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Initial
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        //Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, " Permissions are jddddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Fill with results
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
            perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
        // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // All Permissions Granted
            // insertDummyContact();

            //Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, " Permissions are l", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LaunchApp();

        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Do something after 100
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                    finish();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }

    }
}

public void LaunchApp()
{
    Thread background = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            try {
                // Thread will sleep for 10 seconds
                sleep(4*1000);

                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LoginActivity.class));
                finish();

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    };

    // start thread
    background.start();


}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it isolate the failure? Providing minimized code for the problem will speed up getting the correct answer.

Comment: have you added permissions you are requesting in your manifest file?

Comment: @KaranMer Yeah I have already mmentioned it in my question that i have added it in manifest

Comment: you have not called your permissioncheck() function, call it in onCreate and see if its showing you permission dialog.

Comment: @KaranMer hey. now i noticed this. after the splash screen appears the login page comes so presssed the back button to exit the app. then its asking these permission

Comment: also your handler will start new activity in 3 seconds only, what if user doesnt allow permission in those 3 seconds, instead of using handler, you can start your next activity in `onPermissionResult()`

Comment: @KaranMer hey. now i noticed this. after the splash screen appears the login page comes so presssed the back button to exit the app. then its asking these permission

Comment: use my code working good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 6.0 multiple permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions)

Comment: im put best code use below my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `permissioncheck()` on `onCreate()` method after `setContentView()`. Replace the code provided below with your `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashfile);
    permissioncheck();
}
```

I removed `Handler` codes on `onCreate()` method. Instead, use `onRequestPermissionResult()` and start `LoginActivity` from it. Replace the following code to your `onRequestPermissionResult()`.

```
    @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    //Checking the request code of our request
    if (requestCode == 23) {

        //If permission is granted
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Displaying a toast
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            //Displaying another toast if permission is not granted
            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Needed To Run The App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {
        Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        // Initial
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        perms.put(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        //Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, " Permissions are jddddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // Fill with results
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
            perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
        // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                perms.get(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                perms.get(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // All Permissions Granted
            // Here start the activity
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();

                    }

                }, 3000);

        } else {
            // Permission Denied
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Some Permission is Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

            finish();
        }

    }
}
```

> Please carefully read comments in the code provided above.

Comment: At where shoul i call this?

Comment: hey. now i noticed this. after the splash screen appears the login page comes so presssed the back button to exit the app. then its asking these permission

Comment: I've added more answers to my main answer.

Comment: bro how to use onpermissionresult method and where to use?

Comment: Sorry, I miss typed `onRequestPermissionResult()`. Just replace the code I provided above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183543/discussion-between-zwal-pyae-kyaw-and-aseel-ali).

Comment: I did it but still when i quits the app its asking for permission not after the splash screen

Answer (score 1):

### Best Code

```
 @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
 public class Firstclass extends AppCompatActivity {




private int    timeoutMillis       = 5000;

/** The time when this {@link AppCompatActivity} was created. */

private long                startTimeMillis     = 0;

/** The code used when requesting permissions */

private static final int    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 1234;


public int getTimeoutMillis() {
    return timeoutMillis;
}


@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public Class getNextActivityClass() {
    return SecondActivity.class;
};


public String[] getRequiredPermissions() {
    String[] permissions = null;
    try {
        permissions = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),
                PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS).requestedPermissions;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (permissions == null) {
        return new String[0];
    } else {
        return permissions.clone();
    }
}

@TargetApi(23)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        checkPermissions();
    } else {
        startNextActivity();
    }
}


@TargetApi(23)
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST) {
        checkPermissions();
    }
}

private void startNextActivity() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
    long delayMillis = getTimeoutMillis() - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeMillis);
    if (delayMillis < 0) {
        delayMillis = 0;
    }
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(Firstclass.this, getNextActivityClass()));
            finish();
        }
    }, delayMillis);
}


private void checkPermissions() {
    String[] ungrantedPermissions = requiredPermissionsStillNeeded();
    if (ungrantedPermissions.length == 0) {
        startNextActivity();
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(ungrantedPermissions, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}

@TargetApi(23)
private String[] requiredPermissionsStillNeeded() {

    Set<String> permissions = new HashSet<String>();
    for (String permission : getRequiredPermissions()) {
        permissions.add(permission);
    }
    for (Iterator<String> i = permissions.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String permission = i.next();
        if (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d(Firstclass.class.getSimpleName(),
                    "Permission: " + permission + " already granted.");
            i.remove();
        } else {
            Log.d(Firstclass.class.getSimpleName(),
                    "Permission: " + permission + " not yet granted.");
        }
    }
    return permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]);
 }
 }
```

### Manifest xml permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```