# Unable to request multiple dangerous permissions at once

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I'm working on an app that collects data for processing, as such it requires multiple dangerous permissions (namely `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` and `READ_PHONE_STATE`). At the moment it requests one then crashes.

I have tried requesting the permissions separately using `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions`, and I have tried having both of the permissions in the array. I have also tried using the request codes 0,1 and 7 as I saw these used in different answers to similar questions on this topic, but nothing seems to change.

```java
 private void setupPermissions() {
        ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
        }
        if (permissions.size()>0){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), 7);
        }
    }
```

Expected results:

- Upon first opening the app both permissions should be requested for, either by two separate dialog boxes (one after the other) or by a multiple page dialog box.
- The app should then run as expected

Actual results:

- requests the first
- allows you to continue with the app
- crashes when you try to use a feature that requires the second
- reopen app
- requests the second
- allows app to continue as normal

Comment: paste ```onRequestPermissionsResult()``` code here

Comment: What is your target sdk version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this checkAndRequestPermissions() Method whenevr you want permission

```
private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions() {

    int ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    int READ_PHONE_STATE = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);

    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

    if (READ_PHONE_STATE != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
    }
    if (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray
                (new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), 101);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following code
[(from this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343101/6544105)

```
public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != 
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;

}
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 
  android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONESTATE
};

if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}
```