# How to fix 'show permission dialog ' every time when I send sms?

Tags: java, android

I want to send SMS by android-app, but the permission dialog show before the send a message every time, I supposed to send a message without dialog show after the first permission asked.

My android app is run on mi-8, target SDK-version is 29.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 3);
} else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 4);
} else {
    sendMsg();
}
```

I expect the permission dialog did not show when I send a message after the first asked permission, but actual every time show dialog when I send a message .

Comment: please format your code... and show your entire code

Comment: try this for easy handling of multiple permissions
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343101/8528047

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this function to check whether you have given the permission if say so you have given as required persmission it will return true flag

check by this way

```
   private boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(){

        //add as much as permission you need
        int readSMS = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        int sendSms = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);

        List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        if (readSMS != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS);
        }
        if (receiveSms != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS);
        }
        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
                    REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**check by this way**

```
 if (checkAndRequestPermissions()){
        sendMsg();
    }else{
      //do what you want  
    }
```

no need to do this by hardcode way

Comment: first, thank your reply, I know how to reformat my code, but the problem is not this,  the question is why I granted the permission after sending a message the dialog show again?

Comment: please mention full code if you have manually asked it then it shows the dialog for sure even if you have gave @allenMeng

Comment: ok，thanks, my question will appear depending on android-system.