# onReceive method doesn't get called on the first launch of application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to perform some implementation against the phone call. by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15564021/1925394). Everything works fine except the **onReceive** method from **PhonecallReceiver** doesn't get called on the **first launch** of the application, **afterward**, it works fine. Thanks for your time and help.

PhonecallReceiver

```
public class PhonecallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

//The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;  

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.

        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }


        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);

}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest

protected void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start){}

public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}
```

}

CallReceiver

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhonecallReceiver {

private static CallListener mCallListener;

public static void bindListener(CallListener callListener) {
    mCallListener = callListener;
}

@Override
protected void onIncomingCallReceived(final Context ctx, final String number, Date start) {
    try {
        if (mCallListener != null) {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        stopRinging(ctx);
                        mCallListener.displayNumber(number);
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.example.expphonecall.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.example.expphonecall.CallReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>-->
    </receiver>

</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Where you declare lastState? what value when you init it?

Comment: @CôngHải, code updated

Answer (score 0):

My English expression may not be very good, I hope you can understand

You can make it as `

```
PhoneStateReceiver phoneStateReceiver = new PhoneStateReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    for (String action : actions) {
        intentFilter.addAction(action);
    }
    c.registerReceiver(phoneStateReceiver,intentFilter);
```

`

but not register as static,It well be work?

Or

If your application implement InCallService.

Use call.registerCallback(Call.Callback),the Callback worked No abnormality

Answer (score 0):

Required permissions(READ_PHONE_STATE, CALL_PHONE) were being asked separately in the activity(not a better way)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission has not been granted, therefore prompt the user to grant permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    //MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
                    11);
        }

        if (getApplicationContext().checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Permission has not been granted, therefore prompt the user to grant permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    //MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS);
                    12);
        }
    }
```

And as the request for these permissions is asked [collectively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37546500) then the receiver started to invoke on the first launch of the application

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
};

private void checkPermissions(){

    if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```