# How to set up 3 consecutive requests for permissions immediately after install and opening app?

Tags: android, permissions

I have researched so much for setting up permissions but everything is either outdated or not helpful. I am looking to set up 3 consecutive requests for files, location, and phone permission for my app. Currently it will ask for files permission only and then start running the app. I have to either reset the app for it to ask for the second permissions or go to app info to manually do it. How do I get it to ask for all 3 permissions upon installing and starting the app up for the first time? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions

Comment: Make one request for all three permissions. It sounds like you are making three separate requests. Ideally, your question would include a [mcve] demonstrating what you are trying.