# Android android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT error

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm new to android studio and y have a problem that I can't solve.
I'm trying to enable Bluetooth, so I have done this :

AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
```

MainActivity.java :

```
private void enableBLT(){

    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (adapter == null) {
        dialogNoBlt();
    }
    if (!adapter.isEnabled()) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) ==
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Intent enableBltIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBltIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

        } else {
            Log.d("blt-", "no permission");
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("blt-", "Not enabled");

    }
}
```

But I still have an error "requires android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT", and my app just crash.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Post your stacktrace from logcat & don't post screenshots of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to request `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT` and `Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN` permissions at runtime as well. Just declaring in manifest is not sufficient because they are under dangerous permissions category.

[docs for requesting permission](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Refer the following link of answer for a direct code sample

[requesting multiple permissions at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343101/13396193)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did understand that I needed to ask permission, but not how to do it. Now it works, thanks