# I am developing an app and it asks for multiple permissions when I install it. Is there a way to grant them all in a single click?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, mobile

I am a React Native Developer and developing a banking app. It asks for multiple permissions including camera and location. There are 4-5 pop-ups when I install the app initially asking for permissions which gets pretty annoying for the client as well. They have placed a requirement to use a single pop-up.

Is there a way I can club all these pop-ups in a single one and grant them all together with a single click as the user installs the app initially?

Please suggest for both Android and iOS.

Comment: Is this any help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions

Comment: You cannot combine permission requests in iOS. However, on both iOS and Android it is better to wait until the user access a feature that needs a permission before asking. That way they aren't bombarded with permission requests and they understand the context of the request.  For example if you need the camera to photograph a receipt ask when they first access the receipt scan function, not just when they launch the app.

Comment: No, You can't do that in a single click, This permission pop-up when user use this service or feature at that time pop-up come