# List of Android permissions normal permissions and dangerous permissions in API 23?

Tags: android, permissions, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-api-levels

Which permissions need for requesting permissions at run time of API 23?

Comment: Google now lists the dangerous permissions here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups

Comment: in this moment I found that in order to check the protection level for each permission directly from the Android documentation you have to go to: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#permission-of-interest, e.g. for CAMERA it's https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#CAMERA

Answer (score 199, accepted):

As of API level 23, the following permissions are classified as PROTECTION_NORMAL:

```
ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
BLUETOOTH
BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
BROADCAST_STICKY
CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_STATE
DISABLE_KEYGUARD
EXPAND_STATUS_BAR
GET_PACKAGE_SIZE
INSTALL_SHORTCUT
INTERNET
KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES
MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS
NFC
READ_SYNC_SETTINGS
READ_SYNC_STATS
RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
REORDER_TASKS
REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS
REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
SET_ALARM
SET_TIME_ZONE
SET_WALLPAPER
SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS
TRANSMIT_IR
UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT
USE_FINGERPRINT
VIBRATE
WAKE_LOCK
WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS
```

and

Dangerous permissions  :

```
READ_CALENDAR
WRITE_CALENDAR
CAMERA
READ_CONTACTS
WRITE_CONTACTS
GET_ACCOUNTS
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
RECORD_AUDIO
READ_PHONE_STATE
READ_PHONE_NUMBERS 
CALL_PHONE
ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS 
READ_CALL_LOG
WRITE_CALL_LOG
ADD_VOICEMAIL
USE_SIP
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
BODY_SENSORS
SEND_SMS
RECEIVE_SMS
READ_SMS
RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH
RECEIVE_MMS
READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION
ACCEPT_HANDOVER
ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION
ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
```

Android 6.0 multiple request  permissions [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37546500/1770868)

Source https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: How authentication and gps/location services?

Comment: See this link : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html or https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm

Comment: Wait why is WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE ON THIS LIST. I dont think it is a dangerous permission

Comment: The list has read access to your Google https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE  is a dangerous permission.

Comment: WONDERFUL list of dangerous permissions, @Ahmad. Google doesn't show this list, only the normal permissions. I believe it's now necessary to link to a privacy policy when publishing apps that use one of these dangerous permissions.

Comment: list moved here https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Thanks for these lists. One suggestion though: It would be slightly more helpful if the list of dangerous permissions was in alphabetic order. (I was first confused and was thinking you'd missed a permission, and then found it down at the end of the list.)

Comment: I find it sad that every developer must now learn this list because Android is too dumb to auto-prompt at runtime when a permission is actually needed.  Sadder still that there IS NO LIST of dangerous permissions, except here or in the 10,000 line long file at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Comment: @rmirabelle I was extremely frustrated by this just now, there was a list of this on their documentation but they replace it with a link linking you to their developer docs but it it is not useful because it did not indicate there what is dangerous, from normal etc.

Answer (score 4):

The Normal permissions do not directly affect the user’s privacy. If application lists a normal permission in its manifest, then these permissions will be automatically granted by the system upon installation. Some of the most common normal permissions are given below.

Check and change data connection: Include network state, Wi-Fi State, Bluetooth, Internet, etc.

Example:

[image]

Source: https://vmokshagroup.com/blog/android-runtime-permissions/