# READ_PHONE_STATE permission granted. but sometimes security exception is raised

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I was looking at the Crash report and found a strange crash.

I requested a runtime permission`(`READ_PHONE_STATE`)` for TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() method and it was granted.

Most of them work fine. But sometimes a security exception occurs.
Obviously, The permission was granted when viewed in the log.
Even very rarely happens in the Android 5.x version.

Compared to the total number of users, this crash occurs very rarely. But I do not know why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

its dangerous permission problem.

read this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937109/4993283

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But this is not a dangerous permission requesting issue. Issue is that an security exception is thrown even though dangerous permission is granted. (한국분이시네요 ㅎㅎ)

Answer (score 0):

android 10 need Permission: READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE, and detail on the android document:   https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes