# Android 6.0 permission model for manufacturer permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to add onesignal sdk and their documentation says to add manufacturer level permissions like:

```
   <!-- START: ShortcutBadger -->
    <!-- Samsung -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />

    <!-- HTC -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT" />

    <!-- Sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE" />

    <!-- Apex -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT" />

    <!-- Solid -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE" />

    <!-- Huawei -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />

    <!-- ZUK -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_APP_BADGE" />

    <!-- OPPO -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.oppo.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

My question is do I need to ask for these permissions from user by using java code "onRequestPermissionsResult".

I can't find above permissions in Normal or Dangerous permission list and hence the confusion.
[Normal and Dangerous Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936914/list-of-android-permissions-normal-permissions-and-dangerous-permissions-in-api)

Comment: no, you only need to add these in your Manifest file

Comment: @ShashwatGupta is right. After testing I agree with above comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can check all permission from user side by asking them to allow the permission when he/she installs and open the app first time and accordingly.

```
if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},PERMISSION_CODE); 
    }
```

this will prompt the user to allow the permission.