# Google Play Permission warning?

Tags: android, android-studio

After adding ads in my app this warning appears in google play store 
Warning:
required Permission

```
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

this permissions are dangerous permission i have to add it on run time or simple in Manifiest file thanks
?

Comment: check this [List of Android permissions normal permissions and dangerous permissions in API 23?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36936914/7666442)

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks dear i saw the list and these three permission  are classified as PROTECTION_NORMAL so i'm  adding it in manifiest.xml file then is it enough..

Answer (score 0):

**The thing you need is privacy policy for the app If your app handles personal or sensitive user data**

**Check out this link it should help you for sure**

[Adding a privacy policy to your app's store listing helps provide transparency about how you treat sensitive user and device data.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?visit_id=1-636181561830097288-1046519841&rd=1#privacy)

The problem is there because your app's **Manifest.xml** having these permission to access information from your's device but you don't have privacy policy link while submitting on the play store.