# What does Google Play do with the Privacy Policy Link I provide it with?

Tags: google-play, privacy-policy

I am developing an app that will stand on its own without a Website (at the moment).
According to Google Play, I must provide a Privacy Policy URL because my app requires the android.permission.CAMERA permission.

I know that I can place a Privacy Policy on a static hosted Website and give that URL to Google Play, but I would like to know what Google Play will use that URL for.

Does it just give the users the link and if clicked will take the user to the static page where the privacy policy is hosted?

Does it crawl the page and extracts information from it to display the info within the Play Store?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of permissions : Normal and Dangerous as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936914/list-of-android-permissions-normal-permissions-and-dangerous-permissions-in-api)

> The purpose of a permission is to protect the privacy of an Android
>   user.

Android apps must request permission to access sensitive user data (such as contacts and SMS), as well as certain system features (such as camera and internet). Depending on the feature, the system might grant the permission automatically or might prompt the user to approve the request.

read more here : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

So if you using some of Dangerous level permissions in your app , google will definitely ask you to provide Privacy Policy before uploding apk to playstore .

so if you not provide link , they will not approve your apk build to publish in playstore.

Yes , they also display Privacy Policy Link to all users in **ADDITIONAL INFORMATION** section in Playstore .

For Example See Below Picture :

[image]

Comment: I have provided the privacy policy link in the Play store settings, but it doesnt show up on my app page in the Google Play store. This has caused Facebook to put my app in development mode... 

And as usual, neither Facebook or Google are available for any help. :-(