# Is there a way to send SMS on flutter without user interaction?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to send SMS from my flutter app when a button is pressed. I'd like to do this without user interaction. I know i can launch the SMS app using **url_launcher**.

I tried using the **sms** package from pub but flutter says the api is outdated.

I'd like to do this purely in dart if possible.

Comment: `I'd like to do this without user interaction. ` Sounds dodgy, if you have a sms provider you can do it using a REST service, but don't think it will be possible to send the sms from the user using his resources

Comment: when i said `I'd like to do this without user interaction.`, i meant i want to send sms without opening another page like `flutter_sms` does.
the primary function of the app would be to send an sms to a fixed number, i assume the users that install would know, since it would also ask for permission to send sms.

Comment: @delphix me too, i need to find a way to send sms in the app without using another app. if you find a way please share it.

Comment: @DelphiX were you able to send SMS/MMS without user interaction?

Comment: @SunilDS Yes i was, Its been a while since then. i forked the [repository](https://github.com/geordyvcErasmus/flutter_sms) and made the changes i required. while its regrettable that we dont have a more straight forward option. this gives a starting position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the package [sms_maintained](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained). refer to package for latest version.

Code sample from package.

```dart
import 'package:sms/sms.dart';

void main() {
  SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
  String address = someAddress();
  ...
  sender.sendSms(new SmsMessage(address, 'Hello flutter!'));
}
```

I't provides other methods as well.

Querying, filtering, contact info, receiving and deleting as well.

For sending the a sms you'd need the necessary permissions.

- **SEND_SMS**

And for other functionalities.

- **RECEIVE_SMS**
- **READ_SMS**
- **READ_CONTACTS**

An extensive list of them are located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36936914/list-of-android-permissions-normal-permissions-and-dangerous-permissions-in-api).

flutter **AndroidManifest.xml** is location **=>** *android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml*

**EDIT #:**

The [package](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_maintained) is no longer maintained. you may manually link to files from this [repo](https://github.com/mHaisham/flutter_sms)

pubspec.yaml

```dart
dependencies:
  ...
  sms_maintained:
    path: plugin_folder_path
```