# I can't use library right. App give me error. Can you help me?

Tags: android, compiler-errors, lib

https://github.com/GautamChibde/android-audio-visualizer/wiki/Line-Bar-Visualizer I use this liblary. This my code:
XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aw="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools ="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
    android:layout_height ="match_parent"
    android:id ="@+id/chart_layout"
    tools:context =".MRecorder"
    android:orientation ="vertical"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">
    <com.chibde.visualizer.LineBarVisualizer
        android:id="@+id/visualizer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"/>

</RelativeLayout >
```

Code class .MRecorder:

```
public class MRecorder extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spectr_sound);
        LineBarVisualizer lineBarVisualizer = findViewById(R.id.visualizer);
        //то что он должен проиграть. my music
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample_src_main_res_raw_red_e);

// set custom color to the line.
        lineBarVisualizer.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.av_red));

// define custom number of bars you want in the visualizer between (10 - 256).
        lineBarVisualizer.setDensity(100);

// Set you media player to the visualizer.
        lineBarVisualizer.setPlayer(mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId()); <---Error
    }
}
```

and this my error:

```
E/AudioEffect: set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -1
E/visualizers-JNI: Visualizer initCheck failed -3
E/Visualizer-JAVA: Error code -3 when initializing Visualizer.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.imagewithcamera, PID: 24377
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.imagewithcamera/com.example.imagewithcamera.MRecorder}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2957)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -3
        at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:218)
        at com.chibde.BaseVisualizer.setPlayer(BaseVisualizer.java:81)
        at com.example.imagewithcamera.MRecorder.onCreate(MRecorder.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
```

How can I fix this? I used code how written in documentation, but it give me error

My manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.imagewithcamera"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<!--Добавление прав на камеру-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<!--для записи картинки в файл-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!--для получения доступа к микрофону-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    tools:replace="android:label"
    android:label="Camera2"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MRecorder"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

If you need look my manifest///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Did you add/request  `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` permission?

Comment: @Nitish Yes, I have android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission

Comment: @ADM  Yes, I have android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO permission

Comment: `RECORD_AUDIO` is listed in [runtime permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937109/4168607) . SO you have to ask it at runtime also . R u doing it or not ? By looking at the code i can say you are not . So do it and it should work .

Comment: @ADM I not use this. Thanks, you fixed my problem