# Excessive android permissions provided on flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions, android-manifest

The manifest showing permission which I have not mentioned. The security team raised that you have mentioned many permission which is not in use in the application.

[image]

The above permission is written in the manifest. I have used many plugins/packages in application. is this bcoz of them?

Comment: Libraries, packages will add permissions to `AndroidManifest` depending on their use cases. A few of these are pretty common but do check what permissions are considered dangerous & which are allowed by default. Check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36937109/6819340

Comment: Can we remove or handle them?